# Populate array once and reference later

Tags: c#, arrays, xamarin

I have an app which selects a random word from a text file loaded into an array,

I currently do this:

.xaml:

```
<Label x:Name="GameWords" Text="Press 'Generate a Word' to get started" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

<Button x:Name="GenerateWord" Text="Generate a Word" Clicked="GetWord" />
```

xaml.cs:

```
async void GetWord(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var WordsList = new List<string>();
            using (var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("txtWords.txt"))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    WordsList.Add(line);
                }
            }
            string[] allWords = WordsList.ToArray();
            var random = new Random();
            int randNum = random.Next(1, 267751); /*Max lines in txtWords.txt */
            string newWord = allWords[randNum];
            GameWords.Text = newWord;
        }
```

As you can see, every press of the button loads the entire file txtWords.txt (267751 words) into an array called allWords.

Ideally what I want to do is load the array once, probably on app load, then reference it in GetWord function. If I move the section of code where I load the array outside of the function, I can't seem to reference the array within GetWord?

What's the best way to structure my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about code you aren’t sharing, making it hard to do anything other than provide an alternative implementation of the code you did share...

The code below is a minimal change to the code you shared to make it behave as you say you want it to.  Note that it isn’t thread safe.

```
private static List<string> WordsList;

async void GetWord(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WordsList == null) {
            WordsList = new List<string>();
            using (var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("txtWords.txt"))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    WordsList.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }
        string[] allWords = WordsList.ToArray();
        var random = new Random();
        int randNum = random.Next(1, 267751); /*Max lines in txtWords.txt */
        string newWord = allWords[randNum];
        GameWords.Text = newWord;
    }
```

Comment: The code I shared is essentially the entire code, minus a few unrelated blocks. This code does not achieve quite what I'm after; it's still reading the whole text file to WordsList every time GetWord is called. Appreciate the effort though.

Comment: @WillC: The code you posted, isn’t the code where you can’t reference the array.  As for my modification, I have a typo, WordList vs WordsList, perhaps that was the source of the problem it should only load once.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple and optimized code for extract random text from a file.

```
public string GetRandomText()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int _maxLine = 1000;
    return File.ReadLines("C:\\txtWords.txt").Skip(r.Next(1, _maxLine)).Take(1).First();
}
```

Comment: This looks useful, but how do you use File.ReadLines() with a StreamReader?

Comment: {File.ReadLines()} returns an {IEnumerable<string>} and it does not read the whole file at one go, so it is really a better option when working with large size files.     



From MSDN:
> The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows:

When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you but that's not quite what I asked. Getting the path of a file in an app is not the same as accessing a file on a PC. You can't, as far as I'm aware, give an explicit path (e.g. `"C:\\txtWords.txt"`). I'm using `FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync` which returns a stream for a file contained in the app package. My question is how would I use `ReadLines()` in this situation?

Comment: excuse me i forget about the stream. I think you can store the file on sever then use above example which i sent to you, the cost of writing file is less than reading whole lines,and  this be more efficient than reading all lines.